# Unknown Display // Drivers issue

Tags: debian, proprietary-drivers

My computer configuration is:

Operating System: Dual Boot Windows 10 and Debian 8 Jessie (64 bit)

Motherboard: Asus Z170 PRO Gaming

Graphic card: Nvidia GTX 1080 (Reference/Founder Edition)

Processor: Intel I7-6700K

Memory: 16 GB - 2 x 8GB 3200 mhz (probably crucial, I forgot...)

Hard Discs: SSD m.2 512 GB Liteon (NVMe, Debian 8 Jessie) SSD MX300 1050 GB (Windows 10 installed)

SSD OZ SATA 2 30 GB (nothing already installed, but I will add this space later to my Debian for testing, sandbox, etc...)

Monitor: Dell U3415W (21:9)

After two days when I was trying to make a dual boot system (known issue with GRUB installation on NVMe disc), I finally installed it properly :). Now I have problem with display resolution and other drivers, my current detected resolution is 1024 x 768 (4:3) - "Unknown Display", however it should be 3440x1440 (21:9). Details below:

```
@debian:~$: xrandr

xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768 default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm 1024x768 76.00*

@debian:~$: lspci -v

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 191f (rev 07) Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8694 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0 Capabilities: 

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 1901 (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode]) Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0 Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0 I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff Memory behind bridge: f6000000-f70fffff Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000e0000000-00000000f1ffffff Capabilities:  Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device a12f (rev 31) (prog-if 30 [XHCI]) Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8694 Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 137 Memory at f7330000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K] Capabilities:  Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device a13a (rev 31) Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8694 Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 11 Memory at f734d000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4K] Capabilities: 

00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device a102 (rev 31) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0]) Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8694 Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 155 Memory at f7348000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K] Memory at f734c000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256] I/O ports at f050 [size=8] I/O ports at f040 [size=4] I/O ports at f020 [size=32] Memory at f734b000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K] Capabilities:  Kernel driver in use: ahci

00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a167 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode]) Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0 Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0 Capabilities:  Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a110 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode]) Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0 Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0 Memory behind bridge: f7200000-f72fffff Capabilities:  Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a118 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode]) Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0 Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=0 Memory behind bridge: f7100000-f71fffff Capabilities:  Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device a145 (rev 31) Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8694 Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0

00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Device a121 (rev 31) Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8694 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0 Memory at f7344000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]

00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device a170 (rev 31) Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 86ae Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 156 Memory at f7340000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K] Memory at f7320000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K] Capabilities:  Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device a123 (rev 31) Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8694 Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 11 Memory at f734a000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256] I/O ports at f000 [size=32]

00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V (rev 31) Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8672 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 138 Memory at f7300000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K] Capabilities:  Kernel driver in use: e1000e

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1b80 (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller]) Subsystem: Dell Device 119e Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11 Memory at f6000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M] Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M] Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M] I/O ports at e000 [size=128] Expansion ROM at f7000000 [disabled] [size=512K] Capabilities: 

01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10f0 (rev a1) Subsystem: Dell Device 119e Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17 Memory at f7080000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K] Capabilities:  Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

03:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. Device 1242 (prog-if 30 [XHCI]) Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8675 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16 Memory at f7200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K] Capabilities:  Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Broadcom Corporation (Wrong ID) Device 2200 (rev 01) (prog-if 02 [NVM Express])

Subsystem: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. Device 1093
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
Memory at f7100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: 
Kernel driver in use: nvme
```

I already run apt-get update && apt-get upgrade, but I still have resolution issue. I found few solutions on Ubuntu forum, however it didn't work for me.

My source package list contains only the "main" from https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList (- an example of a sources.list for Debian 8/Jessie. I cannot paste it, because I can't paste more then two links...)

My questions are:

1. What I need to do to fix issue with resolution?
2. Looking into my lspci -v values, can anyone tell me what drivers I'm missing and what I need to do to fix it?
3. Can anyone confirm that my source package list is correct?
4. Is it true that GTx 1080 is only supported by Debian 8 Jessie-backports distribution?

Comment: Welcome to U&L , you can install some packages from `backports` after editing your `/etc/apt/sources.list` ,  more info here https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out that I need to below entry to `sources.list`:

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free.
```

I have added also `contrib non-free` entries, now it looks like below:

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib non-free  
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib non-free

deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main contrib non-free 
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free 
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
```

jessie-backports

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free
```

After that I run:

```
apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[-]-[-]-,,')"

apt-get update

apt-get install -t jessie-backports nvidia-driver
```

As provided in the link by GAD3R (many thanks bro, first beer on me :)). Screen resolution works good now :).

Just to make sure, can anyone check my sources.list? What are the concerns of adding contrib non-free? I read few articles about it, however I would like to hear it from you with simple language.

My `lspci -v`, looks now as:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 191f (rev 07) Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8694 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0 Capabilities: 

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 1901 (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode]) Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0 Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0 I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff Memory behind bridge: f6000000-f70fffff Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000e0000000-00000000f1ffffff Capabilities:  Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device a12f (rev 31) (prog-if 30 [XHCI]) Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8694 Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 137 Memory at f7330000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K] Capabilities:  Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device a13a (rev 31) Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8694 Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 11 Memory at f734d000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4K] Capabilities: 

00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device a102 (rev 31) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0]) Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8694 Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 155 Memory at f7348000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K] Memory at f734c000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256] I/O ports at f050 [size=8] I/O ports at f040 [size=4] I/O ports at f020 [size=32] Memory at f734b000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K] Capabilities:  Kernel driver in use: ahci

00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a167 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode]) Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0 Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0 Capabilities:  Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a110 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode]) Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0 Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0 Memory behind bridge: f7200000-f72fffff Capabilities:  Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a118 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode]) Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0 Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=0 Memory behind bridge: f7100000-f71fffff Capabilities:  Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device a145 (rev 31) Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8694 Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0

00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Device a121 (rev 31) Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8694 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0 Memory at f7344000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]

00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device a170 (rev 31) Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 86ae Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 156 Memory at f7340000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K] Memory at f7320000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K] Capabilities:  Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device a123 (rev 31) Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8694 Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 11 Memory at f734a000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256] I/O ports at f000 [size=32]

00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V (rev 31) Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8672 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 138 Memory at f7300000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K] Capabilities:  Kernel driver in use: e1000e

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1b80 (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller]) Subsystem: Dell Device 119e Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 157 Memory at f6000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M] Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M] Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M] I/O ports at e000 [size=128] [virtual] Expansion ROM at f7000000 [disabled] [size=512K] Capabilities:  Kernel driver in use: nvidia

01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10f0 (rev a1) Subsystem: Dell Device 119e Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17 Memory at f7080000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K] Capabilities:  Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

03:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. Device 1242 (prog-if 30 [XHCI]) Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8675 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16 Memory at f7200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K] Capabilities:  Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Broadcom Corporation (Wrong ID) Device 2200 (rev 01) (prog-if 02 [NVM Express]) Subsystem: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. Device 1093 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16 Memory at f7100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K] Capabilities:  Kernel driver in use: nvme
```

Can you confirm that everything is good?

I also run `glxinfo | grep OpenGL`:

```
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation OpenGL renderer string: GeForce GTX 1080/PCIe/SSE2 OpenGL core profile version string: 4.4.0 NVIDIA 375.26 OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.40 NVIDIA via Cg compiler OpenGL core profile context flags: (none) OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile OpenGL core profile extensions: OpenGL version string: 4.5.0 NVIDIA 375.26 OpenGL shading language version string: 4.50 NVIDIA OpenGL context flags: (none) OpenGL profile mask: (none) OpenGL extensions: OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 NVIDIA 375.26 OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20 OpenGL ES profile extensions
```

Comment: After installing the required package , open the terminal and run `nvidia-xconfig` command to generate the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file then run `nvidia-settings`